# Passing the path in variable in Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell, variables, get-childitem, illegal-characters

When I use `*` in string then `Get-ChildItem` returns the value.

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem "C:\PROD\Logs\exec_package_OrderAnalytics_EXTR.dtsx*"
```

But when I store the path in a variable including `*` then it shows an error:

```
$PackageName = "OrderAnalytics_EXTR.dtsx"
$PackagePath = "\\pdw01rasci001\SSISPackages\PROD\Logs\exec_package_$($PackageName)*"
$Files = Get-ChildItem "$PackagePath"
```

Error message:

```
Get-ChildItem : Illegal characters in path.
At line:25 char:10
+ $Files = Get-ChildItem $PackagePath | Sort-Object -Property CreationT ...`
```

So how should I use `*` as well as variable name in `Get-ChildItem` to get the result?

Comment: Try and only run Get-ChildItem $PackagePath without the double quotes.

Comment: Works for me, I don't get that error message when I copy and paste your code..?

Comment: @Anders: While the enclosing `"..."` aren't necessary, they also make no difference here (unlike in POSIX-like shells, PowerShell's wildcard support does not rely on _unquoted_ arguments).

Comment: AkashPaul: your two examples use different paths - your problem is likely unrelated to the use of variables and instead related to the specific files present in the directory referenced by the UNC path.

Comment: Your error message does not match your code. Please create a [mcve] and post that code and the error message produced by it. Also, please avoid the construct `$($variable)` for inserting variables in strings. The correct way is `${variable}`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, hmm is there a particular reason for ${variable} as opposed to $($variable) or is it just a good practice ?

Comment: @Clint I consider it good practice because of the way subexpressions work. They execute the nested command and return the output, which is then embedded into the string. In case of a variable that simply echoes the value of that variable, so the result is the same as with expanding the variable, and there are cases when you can't avoid it (e.g. for index-access to arrays, object properties, etc.), but IMO it's an uncleaner approach than just expanding a variable. Plus, less special characters improve overall readability. ;)

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, thanks that explains it, explained it elegantly !

Comment: @Clint `${xyz}` with braces is the full syntax for a variable name, that syntax with braces is how you can make variables with odd characters and spaces in the name: `${a-b c } = 1; ${a-b c }` for example. So `"${variable}"` is a slightly more precise `"$variable"`

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler, thank you for the explanation!

Comment: @Akash, May I know if the below answer worked out for you ?

Answer (score 1):

Your script logic and syntax works fine, the issue with your code is likely to do with the path that you have specified. a little bit of debugging of `$PackagePath`should help.

***Try the following script:***

**1. Which will create a directory at "C:\Stackoverflow\Scripts"**

**2. Creates 3 text files within the directory**

**3. Stores the path in a variable including * as per your requirement**

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "C:\Stackoverflow\Scripts" -Force
New-Item -ItemType File -Path "C:\Stackoverflow\Scripts\Untitled1.txt", "C:\Stackoverflow\Scripts\Untitled2.txt", "C:\Stackoverflow\Scripts\Untitled3.txt"


$FileName = "led"
$FilePath = "C:\Stackoverflow\Scripts\\Untit${FileName}*"
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Name "$FilePath"
echo "$Files"
```

---

**A quick pointer**

> To help debug the path try `Get-ChildItem
>   -LiteralPath` and echo the result, Literal Path takes in the path as it is and be sure not to include any wild cards
>
> ```
> $Files = Get-ChildItem -Name -LiteralPath "\\pdw01rasci001\SSISPackages\PROD\Logs\exec_package_OrderAnalytics_EXTR.dtsx"
> echo "$Files"
> ```