# Cannot get a PowerShell script, to run outside of IS

Tags: powershell

Upon Googling, I've inspected something like 10+ threads on this issue, where thus far none have helped and were for the most part too specific in regards to the code that the poster had... I feel I've got nowhere else I can ask (tried ChatGPT, which is of course as useless as ever when it comes to these things), but here. So I hope some of y'all can forgive me.

So below works in ISE, but not inside of Explorer (i.e. when I **double-click**) on the script. Is there any way I can make it work 'normally'? As in execute it through double-clicking. I've got **Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned** enabled. Tried adding **Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms**, didn't help either.

```
$folderPath = "C:\Users\Vlad\Dropbox\Demos"

# Get a list of all files in the folder
$files = Get-ChildItem $folderPath

# Loop through the files and open them
foreach ($file in $files) {
    Invoke-Item $file.FullName
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 25
}

# Minimize all windows
(New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).MinimizeAll()
```

**EDIT:**

• After many tries, I've managed to screenshot the 'flashing' PowerShell window in regards to attempting to make the script work by double-clicking, this is the error that was in it:

```
C:\Users\Vlad\Dropbox\Demos : The term 'C:\Users\Vlad\Dropbox\Demos' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.'
```

• As Paul suggested below, '**Running in a Non-ISE Terminal**' does work for the script, but I'd of course still very much like to open it by double-clicking... Honestly bit insane that PowerShell is this fundamentally flawed tbh.

**SOLUTION:**

Posted/answered by me below.

Comment: What type of files are in the Demo folder? Do those files require other Assemblies?

Comment: @RetiredGeek nope, just a number of .exes...

Comment: @Vladimir, just wanted to clarify, is the code in the post the exact code you're running on your machine? If so, the error seems to indicate that the script you are running resides in the same directory containing the other files you are trying to open. I don't _think_ this is the cause of the error, but I'd be concerned about this creating an infinite loop of the script running itself. On the other hand, if the code you are running isn't the same as what you've posted, I just want to confirm that it still gives you the same error as your actual code?

Comment: @paul_t Yep, it's exactly the same...

Comment: @RetiredGeek Actually, that's wrong. The folder contains shortcuts, which lead to .exes... but yeah, that's eh, it hardly matters one could say mayhap...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thread [Is there a way to make a PowerShell script work by double clicking a .ps1 file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137146/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-powershell-script-work-by-double-clicking-a-ps1-file) — vizmi's answer. That solved it... The thread also contains an explanation by Jeffery Hicks, on why this infernal thing is.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough rep to comment, so I am going to go on the information provided. Apologies in advance if you already tried some of these steps.

---

## Preface

Your code ran fine for me in PowerShell 7 and PowerShell 5 on Windows 10. *Most* of the code also ran fine in PowerShell 7 on Ubuntu 22.04 (the -ComObject flag doesn't seem to exist in PowerShell 7 on Linux, or at least I couldn't find it, I didn't see any mention of this fact in the docs though).

I Mostly program on and use Linux these days and I haven't written any PowerShell scripts for Windows in at least a year.

## EDIT 05/09/2023

I don't know exactly why you're getting the error you are seeing, it seems like PowerShell is trying to execute the path as a command as opposed to consuming it as a parameter to Get-ChildItem.

A few things you can try to troubleshoot this, though idk that they will prove successful would be:

- Wrap the path in single quotes as opposed to double quotes. This will prevent variables from being interpreted in the string and makes things a bit more literal.
- Use the `LiteralPath` parameter for Get-ChildItem before passing the path variable. Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.3#-literalpath) this will use the value of the path as it is literally typed. (Refer to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50196688/22484684) for a little more information on the toppic).
- Instead of using a variable to store the path, try passing it directly to Get-ChildItem just to see if that works. If it does, then the issue has something to do with how you're storing or using the variable.
- You could try using a different directory for testing, if that works, then something is wrong with the directory you are using. My guess would be permissions on the directory, but I am not sure.

## Old Answer

---

### Troubleshooting

##### Stupid Questions First

- Can you verify that the directory you are trying to access with the script exists and that there aren't any typos in the path your code is using?
- If it does exist, are there any files in the directory the script is accessing, or is it currently empty? If it is empty, this script will run and quit in the blink of an eye so you just might not be seeing it.
- Did you try turning it off and back on again :)

##### Explorer.exe Default Application for PowerShell is Notepad

By default Windows has notepad.exe set to be the native application for opening PowerShell scripts when double-clicked in explorer.exe. This is intended as a semi-security feature and prevents accidentally executing PowerShell scripts that you didn't want to (for instance if you have a script that deletes files). If you change that default application to be the native PowerShell instance, that should allow you to run the script instead of launching notepad when you double click.

##### Running in a Non-ISE  Terminal

If you already set the default application to PowerShell and it still isn't running, try opening a normal (non-ISE) PowerShell session, navigating to the folder the script is in and running it with `.\<script_name.ps1>`. If there is an error or issue preventing your script from running, this should (hopefully) let you know what it is. It's possible that the script is actually launching when you double click it, but that it's immediately closing due to an error such as lacking permissions.

##### Running as an Admin

You could also try running the terminal session as an Administrator to see if perhaps you are just running into permissions issues. Just be aware that any child process spawned by your PowerShell script will inherit the Admin privileges. If you're the only one using the PC and are just opening text files this *probably* isn't that big of an issue, but if you're opening arbitrary demo programs from the internet....

To launch PowerShell (or CMD) as an admin, just right click the start button in the task bar and select the option "Windows PowerShell (Admin)".

##### Using a CMD .bat File to Launch the Script

Worst comes to worst, you can always create a batch file that launches the PowerShell script and which also bypasses the execution policy for good measure. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42897554/powershell-executionpolicy-change-bypass) for a detailed response, but the short version is to put the following in the batch file `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy bypass -file "<script_name.ps1>"`

##### Further Reading

It looks like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137146/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-powershell-script-work-by-double-clicking-a-ps1-file) might be related. It goes over issues getting a PowerShell script to run with double click in explorer.exe.

##### Notes

You can use a shortcut in place of the batch file and just put the command directly into the shortcut. I personally prefer the batch file as they're easier to edit (imo), but they're functionally identical so there's no real reason to use one over the other that I can think of offhand.

Nowadays the recommended editing environment for PowerShell scripts is VSCode with the PowerShell Extension installed. See [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/powershell) for some more information. My understanding is that Powershell_ISE is essentially in maintenance mode and won't be receiving any more updates (other than security patches). [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise?view=powershell-7.3#support) has the following to say:

> The PowerShell ISE is no longer in active feature development. As a  shipping component of Windows, it continues to be officially supported for security and high-priority servicing fixes. We currently have no plans to remove the ISE from Windows.
> There is no support for the ISE in PowerShell v6 and beyond. Users looking for replacement for the ISE should use Visual Studio Code with the PowerShell Extension.

I personally do still like the ISE for some things, but VSCode (or VSCodium) is nevertheless the modern supported solution to the problem.

If you want an application you easily launch by double clicking and which you use on multiple computers, PowerShell *might* not be the easiest for this due to how much effort MS puts into making it difficult to launch PS scripts from Explorer. That isn't to say you shouldn't use PowerShell, particularly if it meets other design requirements (such as being available natively on all Windows PC's), just that you will have to jump through a few more hoops than you might have had to with Python, Perl, or Lua (but none of these are natively available on Windows and do have some other challenges of their own).

If none of the above helps, it might be useful to provide details such as what happens when you double click on the script, what the directory structure looks like, letting us know what the default version of PowerShell on your system is see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/install/installing-windows-powershell?view=powershell-7.3#how-to-check-the-version-of-powershell) if you don't know how to find that, and any other information that you can provide to help. You also mentioned that you looked at 10 or so other threads, and that they were either too specific or not relevant; while certainly not necessary it might be beneficial to list some of those threads with a little information on how they failed to help so that way we can avoid re-treading that ground on accident.

I hope that this was helpful, best of luck getting this issue resolved!

Comment: Part 1, 04/09/2023: Thank you for such a comprehensive, elaborate reply Paul! I've been referring to your reply and researching this issue further in the meanwhile. While linearly going through your list of suggestions, I can confirm that the script runs in regards to 'Running in a Non-ISE Terminal', but again, when double-clicking it, it fail… I have however managed to figure out what the error was, which I've added in the 'EDIT:' section of the OP… Would really appreciate if you had any input on that. I've tried all the other things in your reply, with none of them working unfortunately

Comment: Part 2, 04/09/2023: There is a section of it I'd like to comment on also, but I feel it's best to just scope in on the 'EDIT:' for now, and then if possible, return to the rest later...

Comment: @Vladimir, I've updated the question with some extra steps you can try, but if those don't work I think I've run out of ideas. Sadly I haven't been able to re-create this issue as of yet which is making it difficult to identify the problem (and ergo the correct solution). Best of luck, hopefully you can figure this out.

Comment: Thanks for this (and your patience). I've tried the new suggestions of 'EDIT 05/09/2023', but alas, it hasn't helped... gonna sometime get in touch with someone knowledgeable about PowerShell, so I can eventually sort this out.

Comment: Just wanted you to know that I eh, I guess I should've Googled 'PowerShell double clicking and Run with PowerShell are different' a good bit earlier, but then going through your suggestions, was what ultimately helped me to formulate the bridge to the answer. So thanks for that.